# xsl: Store multiple items in a variable or param for later use

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon

I need to transform an xml to some custom xml format.

In the new format i would have many `sections` node and for each node i am creating a unique id using:

```
<xsl:attribute name="identifier">
                <xsl:variable name="uid" select="util:randomUUID()"/>A<xsl:value-of select="util:toString($uid)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I need a way to store all of these Ids in a list or array so that i can refer it back from some other template and use them in for-each loop.

Is there a way to do this with xsl?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have these globally declared**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vrtfRandList">
 <xsl:for-each select="yourNodeSet">
  <rand><xsl:value-of select="util:randomUUID()"/></rand>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="vRandlist" select="ext:node-set($vrtfRandList)/*"/>
```

**Then later use**:

```
$vRandlist[$k]
```

**Using XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vRandlist" as="xs:integer*"
     select="for $i in 1 to count(yourNodeSet)
              return 
                 util:randomUUID()
            "/>
```

Comment: @AnkurMittal: I also added an XSLT 2.0 solution.